# Overridden method not called in Typescript (Angular project)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, overriding, datetimepicker

I am trying to override a public method from a third-party class, yet it does not call the overriding method.

The method signature is identical and I even used the override keyword and set the 'noImplicitOverride' flag ts.config to confirm my method is actually overriding the super's. Yet it still calls the super's method (located in an mjs file under node modules) instead the overriding method.

**More detailed info**

I'm working on an Angular project and we are using Material DateTimePickers. We've recently replaced Moment with Luxon. Material provide a LuxonDateAdapter to use Luxon with its DateTimePickers (@angular/material-luxon-adapter), but unfortunately this doesn't support time, only dates, so I've had to create my own DateTimeAdapter for Luxon named MatLuxonDatetimeAdapter which extends LuxonDateAdapter. I've then manually added all the missing  parsing/formatting functions to do with time.

It was all going well until I realised the 'parse' method in the LuxonDateAdapter isn't behaving how we want it to. No problem, I'll just override the method and tweak it. Unfortunately this is where the problem began. Even though LuxonDateAdapter's parse method is public, when I override it it seems to completely ignore my override method and instead calls the super's.

**In my MatLuxonDatetimeAdapter  class**

```
@Injectable()
export class MatLuxonDatetimeAdapter extends LuxonDateAdapter {

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) matDateLocale: string,
    @Inject(MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS) options: MatLuxonDateAdapterOptions) {
    super(matDateLocale, options);
  }

 override parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): DateTime | null {
    console.log('This isn't being called!)'
    return null;
  }

 //... other methods which probably aren't relevant
}
```

**In the class declaration for LuxonDateAdapter**

```
export declare class LuxonDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<DateTime> {

parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): DateTime | null;

//... other method declarations which probably aren't relevant
}
```

I can't figure out why it isn't calling my overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Material has both a DatetimeAdapter and a DateAdapter. If the datepicker only uses dates, it utilises the DateAdapter. If it uses both dates and times, it uses the DatetimeAdapter. In my module, I was only providing the DatetimeAdapter implementation. As my datepicker was only using dates, my DatetimeAdapter class wasn't even being used.